# Using Meteor browser-policy package allowOriginForAll for AWS works on http site but not https

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, amazon-s3, meteor

So we are using the Meteor browser-policy package, and using Amazon S3 to store content.

On the server we have setup the browser policy as follows:

```
BrowserPolicy.content.allowOriginForAll('*.amazonaws.com');
BrowserPolicy.content.allowOriginForAll('*.s3.amazonaws.com');
```

This works fine in local dev and in production when visiting our http:// site. However when using the https:// address to our site the AWS content no longer passes this policy.

The following error is put on the console

```
Refused to load the image 'http://our-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/asset-stored-in-s3.png' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src data: 'self' *.google-analytics.com *.zencdn.net *.filepicker.io *.uservoice.com *.amazonaws.com *.s3.amazonaws.com".
```

As you can see we have some other origins allowed in the browser policy, these all seem to work fine in both http and https. AWS S3 is the only one that is failing.

I've tried Chrome, Firefox, and Safari and they all have the same issue.

Whats going on?

Comment: A few questions: Are you getting this in some browsers and not others? Are you using a protocol-relative url? Is that literally the error you see - i.e. you are accessing via https but the site is using an http url?

Comment: Sorry I should have stated that I've tried this in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari and I am getting the same in all browsers. Yes that is the error I see, and we are trying to load s3 data with http urls. I will try to access the s3 bucket items via https and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I may not have the exact answer to this question but I have some information which the community may find helpful.

First, you should avoid serving [mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent). I'm unclear if that would set off the browser policy alerts but you just shouldn't do it anyway. The easiest solution is to use a [protocol-relative-url](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) or just explicitly specify `https` in your url.

Second, I too assumed that the wildcard worked like a [glob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29). However, I've been told that it works the same way as an ssl certificate rule - i.e. for all subdomains or for a specific subdomain. In other words, `*.example.com` and `www.example.com`, are valid but `*.foo.example.com`, isn't meaningful. I think you want to explicitly add your bucket like so:

```
BrowserPolicy.content.allowOriginForAll('our-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com')
```

unless you literally want to trust all of `amazonaws.com`.